# Pathfinding, path-finding or path finding?

Tags: orthography

I'm writing my thesis about finding paths in certain graphs but have run into a spelling problem... Is the correct word "pathfinding", "path finding" or "path-finding"? My spellcheck does not think "pathfinding" is correct and suggests "path finding" or "path-finding" (however the wikipedia article on the subject is called "pathfinding"...). I can't find any definite source on which spelling is to be preferred?

Comment: James Feminore Cooper wrote a famous American book called *The Pathfinder* (one word) in 1840. I can find "pathfinding" (one word) in Google books starting in the 1870s. I think you're fine, and your spellchecker is ignorant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "correct" in English is really defined by what is commonly used and commonly understood. As such I think you're fine with "pathfinding" as it fits both of those criteria.

Having said that it may also be worth checking whether your institution has a style guide that you need to adhere to for your thesis if you're really worried.